# Can I have any way (such as an API) to count the like and react on my post in my page and use that count to store in my database to use it?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, web-applications, webapi

I want to create a post in my web site and post/share it in my Facebook page. This can be live/video/image etc. The amount likes and reaction my post get in Facebook will need to be fetched and stored in my post related database of my website.

- **Is it somehow possible to do?**
- **If it is possible then what tools or guideline I need to follow?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to save the post ID when you create a post (Which you will get if the post was successfully created via the API) [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/post/)

And when you want to get the likes, use that post ID and fetch the API for the information. [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page-post/likes/)

Comment: There is no text in the two links.

Comment: @Shuvo does https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/publishing/ work for you? That one links to the first part, creating a post